# How do I delete directions in gmaps4rails

Tags: gmaps4rails

I have a show action where I show the directions like this:

```
= gmaps({"direction"   => { "data" => { "from" => "#{@ride.latitude},#{@ride.longitude}", "to" => "#{@ride.spot.latitude},#{@ride.spot.longitude}" } }})
```

I want the user to edit the model and update the directions via javascript.
so i have a coffe script here that looks like this:

```
$('#ride_address').autocomplete {
    select: (event,ui) ->

      Gmaps.map.direction_conf.destination = "#{spot_lat},#{spot_lng}"
      Gmaps.map.direction_conf.origin = "#{ride_lat},#{ride_lng}" 
      Gmaps.map.create_direction()

}
```

now the new directions are rendered on the map, 
BUT on TOP of the existing directions.

how can i delete the previous directions first?

Comment: that's not implemented in the gem now. I fear you shoul reinitialize the map

Comment: hi, now i have a call to Gmaps.map.initialize() before the Gmaps.map.create_direction() and its working fine! thanks for the tip

Comment: Great news, nice this workaround suits you